# How to toggleRuler for a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do you toggleRuler through code instead of going through the menu items every time you want it?

```
[textView toggleRuler:self];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[textView setRulerVisible:FALSE];
```

From the class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: BTW, the method has to be implemented in the awakeFromNib method in order it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but maybe someone could use it

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    if (![self.textView isRulerVisible]) {
        [self.textView toggleRuler:nil];
    }
}
```